# What dev folder allows you tell the OS to cache something?

Tags: files, cache, ram

Someone told me that there is a sub folder off of dev that basically allows you to tell the OS to keep the contents of that folder cached in RAM. So if I put some files & directories in `/dev/somefolder` the OS would keep this folder's content cached.

What folder is that? I'm on ubuntu 12.04, in case that matters.

Comment: "Cache" as disk cache? memory cache?

Comment: @Braiam not totally sure. I think it means keep it in RAM

Comment: Not in RAM but in virtual memory. If you have a swap area configured, that makes a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `/dev/shm`, which is a RAM-backed filesystem. This isn't the same as caching as a cache means the file also resides on disk. With `/dev/shm`, which is a [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) filesystem, the files exist in memory only.

Note that you can mount tmpfs volumes anywhere:

```
mount -t tmpfs none /foo/bar
```

There is just one usually mounted at `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, `tmpfs` is not RAM-backed but Virtual-Memory-backed, i.e. the files blocks are stored either in RAM or on disk (in the swap area unless of course you have none). That gives `tmpfs` several advantages compared to traditional RAM disks implementations.