# How do you move files into the in-memory file system mounted at /dev/shm

Tags: filesystems, osx

Someone recently told me about /dev/shm. You all helped refine my understanding of what /dev/shm is [What dev folder allows you tell the OS to cache something?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151849/what-dev-folder-allows-you-tell-the-os-to-cache-something)

The person who told me about /dev/shm said that I could use it to, say, unzip a big file more quickly than in a regular file system. I'm trying to do that now on an OS X machine. I run

```
sudo cp /Volumes/USB/rcv1rcv2aminigoutte.tar.bz2 /dev/shm
```

and get

```
cp: /dev/shm: Operation not supported
```

How do I load a file from the regular file system into the in memory file system mounted at /dev/shm

Thanks as always. I learn a ton from asking questions on this site.

Answer (score 11):

To my knowledge `/dev/shm` is a Linux-only feature. I just doubled checked on my OSX 10.9.4 system and it definitely does not have `/dev/shm`.

Now given OSX is rooted in Unix I would be very surprised if it did not have something similar, so searching for the equivalent led me to this SO Q&A titled: [Does OS X have an equivalent to /dev/shm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033362/does-os-x-have-an-equivalent-to-dev-shm), which in turn led me to this URL titled: [Blazing Fast Firefox using OSX RamDisk](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2008/12/18/blazing-fast-firefox-using-osx-ramdisk/).

This page showed this script which is creating a RamDisk on OSX:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script to enable the Ramdisk for Firefox profiles
VolumeName="Mozilla"

# Size in MB, make sure it is not too low or too high
SizeInMB=220

NumSectors=$((2*1024*SizeInMB))

DeviceName=`hdid -nomount ram://$NumSectors`

echo $DeviceName

diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ RAMDisk $DeviceName

# move the current profiles folder
mv Profiles Profiles_ &&

# make a symlink to the ramdisk
ln -s /Volumes/RAMDisk ./Profiles &&

# then copy it to the ramdisk
/bin/cp -r Profiles_/* Profiles
```

Specifically this line:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ RAMDisk $DeviceName
```

So now we've learned that this types of devices in OSX lingo are called RAM Disks (they're actually called this on Linux and other OSes too, but I'm just showing you how to decompose these types of questions yourself for future reference).

This page had even more info and a link to a GUI tool, [RAM Disk Creator](http://bogner.sh/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/RAMDiskCreator.app_.zip), which you could use to construct your own RAM Disks on OSX too.

- [How to Create a 4GB/s RAM Disk in Mac OS X](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/)

**excerpt**

Here's a sample command on how to construct your own.

```
$ diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://8388608`
```

Which looks like this when you run it:

[image: ss#1]

**NOTE:** You can use this method to calculate the value for `ram://XXXXX` like so:

> Replace the X characters with a number that represents the block size
>   for the total capacity of your RAM Disk. Calculate this number by
>   multiplying your desired size of disk in megabytes by 2048. In our
>   example, we’ll create a 4 GB RAM Disk, which requires a number of
>   8388608 (4096 * 2048).

Comment: Beware that `tmpfs` based file system, available at least on Linux, BSDs and Solaris are not RAM disks. They store the files on virtual memory, not (directly) on RAM. They are then more efficient and far more flexible than the OSX `RAMdisk`.